# Java: Simple Client Server message exchange not working

Tags: java

I am new to Java just started yesterday. I wrote a very simple client server java code. Client sends a message to server. The Server should display that message. And the Server should send a message to client after receiving the message. The client should display the message sent by server.

Server Code,

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class CustomServer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       final int SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 8081;

       try{
         ServerSocket serverObj = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT_NUMBER);
         Socket clientSocketObj = serverObj.accept();
         BufferedReader clientInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocketObj.getInputStream()));
         BufferedWriter clientOutputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocketObj.getOutputStream()));

        if(clientSocketObj != null){
            System.out.println("Client Connected to Server!");

            // Recieve Message from Client
            System.out.println("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT");
            System.out.println(clientInputStream.readLine());

            // Send Message to Client
            clientOutputStream.write("SERVER: Hello Client!");

            // Close Streams
            clientOutputStream.close();
            clientInputStream.close();
        }
        serverObj.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Client,

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class CustomClient{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final String HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";
        final int SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 8081;

        try{
           Socket clientSocket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, SERVER_PORT_NUMBER);
           BufferedWriter clientOutputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
           BufferedReader clientInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
           System.out.println("Connecting....");

        if(clientSocket != null){
            System.out.println("Connected to Server!");

            // Send message to Server
            clientOutputStream.write("CLIENT: HELLO SERVER");

            // Recieve message from Server
            System.out.println("MESSAGE FROM SERVER");
            System.out.println(clientInputStream.readLine());

            // Close Streams
            clientInputStream.close();
            clientOutputStream.close();
        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Neither the Server or Client receive the message. Stuck in some loop. Anyone know why?

Comment: `readline` is expecting a new line terminator (`\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`), `write` isn't sending on

Comment: Didn't work. Tried all 3 combination. Still same behaviour.

Comment: You also need to call `flush` on the `BufferedWriter`, as it won't have written all the content to the underlying stream ... kind of the point of buffer implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a read of the [`BufferedReader`'s JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--), which state

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed

`BufferedWriter#write` is not sending this, so the reader is still waiting.

A simply solution might be to use [`BufferedWriter#newLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) after the `write`

And don't forget to [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush--) the buffer when you're finished writing to it!

You may also want to take a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which will provide a better resource management solution

## `CustomClient`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class CustomClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";
        final int SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 8081;

        try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, SERVER_PORT_NUMBER)) {
            try (BufferedWriter clientOutputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    BufferedReader clientInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))) {
                System.out.println("Connecting....");
                System.out.println("Connected to Server!");

                // Send message to Server
                clientOutputStream.write("CLIENT: HELLO SERVER");
                clientOutputStream.newLine();
                clientOutputStream.flush();

                // Recieve message from Server
                System.out.println("MESSAGE FROM SERVER");
                System.out.println(clientInputStream.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

## `CustomServer`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class CustomServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 8081;

        try (ServerSocket serverObj = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT_NUMBER)) {
            try (Socket clientSocketObj = serverObj.accept()) {
                try (BufferedReader clientInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocketObj.getInputStream()));
                        BufferedWriter clientOutputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocketObj.getOutputStream()))) {

                    System.out.println("Client Connected to Server!");

                    // Recieve Message from Client
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT");
                    System.out.println(clientInputStream.readLine());

                    // Send Message to Client
                    clientOutputStream.write("SERVER: Hello Client!");
                    clientOutputStream.newLine();
                    clientOutputStream.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx worked with flush(). I did add flush() before but I guess I forgot about newline delimiter.